# How to convert this String to Timestamp

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

i have a column with the Data like this "08.06.2017/10:20:46". Data Type is string. i want to convert it into timestamp.
i tried CAST("08.06.2017/10:20:46" AS TIMESTAMP) but it doesn't work
Can you please help me to convert it??
Thanks

Comment: Can anybody please help me?

Comment: which rbdms are you using? mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For mysql, there is a function called [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

You should call it like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(string , format)
```

Take a look at
[Format specifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

In your case I'd try with

```
STR_TO_DATE('08.06.2017/10:20:46','%d.%m.%Y/%H:%i:%s')
```

**Edit:** sorry about the mysql stuff, don't know if I'm supposed to remove it or not... Anyways, for impala, this could get you started:

```
cast(unix_timestamp('08.06.2017/10:20:46', "dd.MM.yyyy/HH:mm:ss") as timestamp)
```

The casting is because unix_timestamp function returns a bigint (take a look **[here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html)** for more information about the impala datetime functions)

Comment: Thanks D le for your help. Unfornately your SQL on Mysql doesn't work on Impala. Impala use another SQL funtion rather than mysql.

Comment: I have edited my answer with some Impala reference hoping I would shed some light on your problem :)

Comment: Thanks D le. that's great. Can you please explain why can we use unix_timestamp? i have thought that this function will only work with datetime but it works with String now. and why we need to use dd.MM.yyyy/HH:mm:ss?

Comment: I've highlighted the link I posted in the last part of my answer to help you with that (in the **here** word). Summarizing, there are three implementations of unix_timestamp: unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp(string datetime), unix_timestamp(string datetime, string format), unix_timestamp(timestamp datetime). I've shown you the third one, which takes as parameters one date-string and one format-string. The format string must match your input date-string's format... and that's it :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle SQL,

use to_date function as below,

`SELECT TO_DATE('08.06.2017/10:20:46','dd.mm.yyyy/hh:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;`

This conveys that the string is in this(dd.mm.yyyy/hh:mi:ss) form of date and convert to date column...

Answer (score 1):

Hive and Impala deals with dates in a similar manner. You need to use the function unix_timestamp to accept non standard date formats, then use from_unixtime function to convert to a timestamp. Below code should work for your example.

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('08.06.2017/10:20:46','dd.MM.yyyy/hh:mm:ss'));
```